# Telegram API: Client is not yet ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, message, telegram

I try to read my Telegram msgs in NodeJS, using the telegram.link lib (NOT the bot API, but the native CLI one).

After setting my client I get this error:

```
Error: Client is not yet ready!
    at Client.isReady (C:\Users\Guilh\WebstormProjects\telegram-link-test\node_modules\telegram.link\lib\telegram.link.js:353:28)
    at Object.callService (C:\Users\Guilh\WebstormProjects\telegram-link-test\node_modules\telegram.link\lib\utility.js:22:17)
    at Account.updateStatus (C:\Users\Guilh\WebstormProjects\telegram-link-test\node_modules\telegram.link\lib\api\account.js:45:20)
    at Timeout.setTimeout (C:\Users\Guilh\WebstormProjects\telegram-link-test\app\main.js:30:24)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

My code is the following:

```
var t = require('telegram.link');
var os = require('os');

var telegramLink = require('telegram.link')();

// set the  environment
var app = {
    id: 000000,
    hash: 'A HASH KEY',
    version: require('../package.json').version,
    lang: 'en',
    deviceModel: os.type(),
    systemVersion: os.platform() + '/' + os.release(),
    connectionType: 'TCP'
};

var primaryDC = t.TEST_PRIMARY_DC;
//var primaryDC = t.PROD_PRIMARY_DC;

var client = telegramLink.createClient(app, primaryDC, ()=> {
    console.log('Created');
    client.account.updateStatus(false).then(()=> {
        client.registerOnUpdates((update)=> {
            console.log('Update received');
            client.messages.receivedMessages(update.id, (err)=> {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Even when putting in a setTimeout, I get this error.
I presume I am missing a step in authentification.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the callback pass any arguments that you should be using / checking? Like `error`?

Comment: Yes the call back of createClient() returns the error "telegram-link Client is not yet ready!"